# Angular 7: injection with dependencies for ngComponentOutlet

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ng-component-outlet

I need to use some kind of `@Input()` decorator for my `ngComponentOutlet`.

But seems that Angular hasn't this feature. Instead, all things that I want to pass inside my outlet components should be provided via `Injector`.

And it's fine if I want to initiate the thing I want provide to inside injectable class. But I need to dive deeper and provide some kind of observable variable (`Observeble<number>` type for example) at creation Injector step. But I can't to get observable variable inside outlet component. Getting following error: `NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!`.

Here is an example of code, I got this pattern from angular docs ([angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)) and modified a little:

```
@Injectable()
export class Greeter {
    suffix$: Observable<number> = null;
    constructor(private _suffix$: Observable<number>) {
        this.suffix$ = this._suffix$;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'complete-component',
    template: `Complete: {{ greeter.suffix$ | async }}`
})
export class CompleteComponent {
    constructor(public greeter: Greeter) {
        this.greeter.suffix$.subscribe(data => console.log('data', data));
        // not working
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'ng-component-outlet-complete-example',
    template: `
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="CompleteComponent; 
                                        injector: myInjector;"
    })
export class NgTemplateOutletCompleteExample {
    CompleteComponent = CompleteComponent;
    myInjector: Injector;

    suffix$: Observable<number> = of(3);

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        this.myInjector =
            Injector.create({providers: [{provide: Greeter, deps: [this.suffix$]}], parent: injector});
    }
}
```

So how can I get and subscribe into this `$suffix` variable inside outlet component.

**P.S.** If I provide `NgTemplateOutletCompleteExample` into the `deps` array and get `NgTemplateOutletCompleteExample.suffix$` inside injectable component `Greeter` - it will work. But the thing is I have a lot of `NgTemplateOutletCompleteExample` components and this thing invalid in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is that Injector - is a static injector. So, to provide any data inside component oultet (or get out any callbacks) I must use `useValue` instead `deps`.

Contructor in `NgTemplateOutletCompleteExample` should be like this:

```
constructor(injector: Injector) {
    this.myInjector =
        Injector.create({providers: [{provide: Greeter, deps: [], useValue: {suffix$: this.suffix$}], parent: injector});
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your update. NgDynamicComponent is not solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for dynamic injection of components taking Inputs and returning Outputs. Natively, Angular does not support `@Input()` and `@Output` on dynamic components.

You can use the package NgDynamicComponent: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component.

## NgComponentOutlet syntax support

**The package supports the NgComponentOutlet syntax as you can see here : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component#ngcomponentoutlet-support**

From what I see from your code, it's what you are asking for: NgComponentOutlet + Inputs support.

## Custom dynamic injector for more advanced stuff

You can also create a custom injector: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component#extra

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why you're getting that error, I'd recommend having at look at [Dependency Providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) from the docs.

The error comes from here

```js
Injector.create({providers: [{provide: Greeter, deps: [this.suffix$]}], parent: injector});
```

To put it briefly, the `deps` array must be a list of **valid DI tokens** and there is no token configured for `this.suffix$`.

Quoted from the sources(Angular 8.0.0)

```js
export interface FactorySansProvider {
  /**
   * A function to invoke to create a value for this `token`. The function is invoked with
   * resolved values of `token`s in the `deps` field.
   */
  useFactory: Function;

  /**
   * A list of `token`s which need to be resolved by the injector. The list of values is then
   * used as arguments to the `useFactory` function.
   */
  deps?: any[];
}
```

Here is one way to solve it:

```js
const OBS_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('obs');

@Injectable()
export class Greeter {
  greeterProp = 'hello!';

   constructor (@Inject(OBS_TOKEN) public suffix$: Observable<any>) {
    console.log('[GREETER]', this.suffix$)
  }
}

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class NgTemplateOutletCompleteExample {
 /* ... */

 myInjector = Injector.create({
    providers: [
      { provide: Greeter, deps: [OBS_TOKEN], },
      { provide: OBS_TOKEN, useValue: this.dummyObs$ },
    ],
    parent: this.inj,
  })

 /* ... */
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?embed=1&file=src/app/ng-comp-outlet/ng-comp-outlet.module.ts)